# Error invoking command! when deploying war to WebSphere Liberty server using Maven Cargo

Tags: java, maven, websphere, cargo

I'm currently trying to deploy a war file to a Websphere Liberty server.

```
    <profile>
        <id>integration</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.6.11</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- Container configuration -->
                        <container>
                            <containerId>websphere85x</containerId>
                            <type>installed</type>
                        </container>
                        <configuration>
                            <type>existing</type>
                            <home>WebSphere server location</home>
                        </configuration>
                        <deployables>
                            <deployable>
                                <artifactId>artifact</artifactId>
                                <groupId>com.group</groupId>
                                <type>war</type>
                            </deployable>
                        </deployables>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

When I run

> cargo:deploy -Pintegration

I get the following error

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2->plugin:1.6.11:deploy (default-cli) on project artifact: Execution >default-cli of goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.6.11:deploy >failed: Deploy failed: Cannot execute jython script. Error invoking command! >Cannot run program "null\bin\wsadmin.bat": CreateProcess error=2, The system >cannot find the file specified

Anyone know what is causing this?

What plugin\dependency I should use to get wsadmin.bat?

Or how I can fix this problem?

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**

I am almost able to get this working
The new config is below

```
<profile>
    <id>integration</id>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
                <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.11</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- Container configuration -->
                    <container>
                        <containerId>liberty</containerId>
                        <type>installed</type>
                    </container>
                    <configuration>
                        <home>LibertyServer</home>
                    </configuration>
                    <deployables>
                        <deployable>
                            <artifactId>SIS-AM-CONSOL-GSPWeb</artifactId>
                            <groupId>com.group</groupId>
                            <type>war</type>
                        </deployable>
                    </deployables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
```

The issue now is that the war file is getting deployed to

> LibertyServer\servers\defaultServer\apps

While the correct location should be

> LibertyServer\usr\servers\defaultServer\apps

I have been looking at [the reference guide](https://codehaus-cargo.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/CARGO/pages/491622/Maven2+Plugin+Reference+Guide) but I don't see a way to have a custom directory.

I did try to add

```
<files>
    <copy>
        <file>war file</file>
        <toDir>LibertyServer\usr\servers\defaultServer\apps</toDir>
        <overwrite>true</overwrite>
    </copy>
</files>
```

Into the configuration settings.

But as expected this did not work.

Any ideas?

Thanks again.

Comment: Your current configuration is for tWAS not for Liberty. You should use `<containerId>liberty</containerId>` for Liberty. If it is working now, add your working config as answer for reference for others.

Answer (score 0):

Update `<home>WebSphere server location</home>` to point to your WAS_HOME location.  When it tries to locate wsadmin to execute the jython script, it's failing: null\bin\wsadmin.bat.  null should be the value of WAS_HOME...

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Unfortunately wsadmin.bat is not in that bin folder :-(. Any suggestions on how I could generate it?

Comment: If you're on a Win box and wsadmin.bat is not in WAS_HOME/bin, your installation of WAS has a problem

Answer (score 0):

Got the deployment working with the following code

```
<profile>
    <id>integration</id>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
                <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.11</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- Container configuration -->
                    <container>
                        <timeout>600000</timeout>
                        <containerId>liberty</containerId>
                        <type>installed</type>
                        <home>ServerHome</home>
                    </container>
                    <configuration>
                        <type>standalone</type>
                        <home>ServerHome</home>
                    </configuration>
                    <deployables>
                        <deployable>
                            <artifactId>Artifact</artifactId>
                            <groupId>com.group</groupId>
                            <type>war</type>
                        </deployable>
                    </deployables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
```

Also it seems that you cannot configure where the war file is deployed to.
It will only deploy to defaultServer.